# Cannot figure out how to remove shower handle

Tags: shower, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

I have been having problems with the hot water knob of my shower, whereby the water pressure gets very low, especially after the knob is turned off tight. I am then able to restore the pressure by turning the knob all the way out (open), but am afraid that eventually this "fix" will stop working. Therefore, I am trying to disassemble the knob so that I can hopefully find and correct the problem. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove it. There is absolutely no screw or removable cap anywhere to be found (see photos). I believe it may be a Kohler, but am not 100% sure. It was already there when I bought the house in 1994.

[image: Knob]

[image: Knob]

[image: Knob][image: Knob]

Comment: Can you turn or remove the white collar up against the wall??  There might be a screw behind it that will allow you to pull off the handle and sleeve exposing the valve stem....

Comment: Hi, yes, I tried that (pulling the escutcheon away from the wall), but still wasn't able to see anything obvious. Thanks a lot for the idea, though. Appreciate it.

Comment: Any chance you can just pull it straight out? I know that some handles don't have screws and are just shoved onto the stems and have to be pried off. I'm grabbing at straws.

Comment: JACK - thanks so much for your suggestions. I'm not sure if it can be pulled off, and am afraid to try. Unfortunately, there aren't any shutoff valves for the shower (when they were installed it probably wasn't code, as I believe it is now), so I'd have to shut off the whole house, and if I then run into a problem, I'd be in big trouble. Thanks again for your thoughts. You may be correct.